# Get-WinEvent search for all errors

Tags: powershell

running Get-WinEvent it's possible to use wildcards:

```
Get-WinEvent -filterhashtable 
@{logname="*";providername="*cluster*";starttime="04.01.2022";endtime="05.31.2022";level=2} - 
ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

but using only wildcards for both logname and providername (surprisingly) doesn't return any records:

```
Get-WinEvent -filterhashtable 
@{logname="*";providername="*";starttime="04.01.2022";endtime="05.31.2022";level=2} - 
ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

so: how to search for all errors in every log from every provider in a given timespan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StartTime` and `EndTime` should be of type `DateTime`, but you supply **strings** that may or may not be convertable to datetime objects.
See [Get-WinEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent) parameter `-FilterHashtable`

Since providing a single wildcard `*` for parameters `LogName` and `ProviderName` apparently doesn't work, you can first retrieve all valid lognames and provider names present in the system as string arrays and use those:

```
# get an array of all Log names
$logNames     = [string[]](Get-WinEvent -ListLog *).LogName
# below line is bound to give you exceptions, so use SilentlyContinue
$logProviders = [string[]](Get-WinEvent -ListProvider * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Name

$startDate    = (Get-Date -Year 2022 -Month 4 -Day 1).Date  # set to midnight
$endDate      = $startDate.AddMonths(2).AddDays(-1)         # calculate 2 months duration    
$filter       = @{LogName=$logNames; ProviderName=$logProviders; StartTime=$startDate; EndTime=$endDate; Level=2}
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $filter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

<sup>Using the start and end date as strings like `"04.01.2022"` *MAY* work in your system, but if you are in a different part of the world and therefore use a different system locale these strings could very well not be convertable to DateTime objects. Therefore it is always best to use the correct datatype as stated in the documentation.</sup>

---

As per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent) parameter LogName:

*"The Get-WinEvent cmdlet queries the Windows API which has a limit of 256. This can make it difficult to filter through all of your logs at one time. You can work around this by using a loop to iterate through each log"*,

perhaps better use a loop like

```
# below line is bound to give you exceptions, so use SilentlyContinue
$logProviders = [string[]](Get-WinEvent -ListProvider * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Name
$startDate    = (Get-Date -Year 2022 -Month 4 -Day 1).Date  # set to midnight
$endDate      = $startDate.AddMonths(2).AddDays(-1)         # calculate 2 months duration 

Get-WinEvent -ListLog * | ForEach-Object {
    $filter = @{LogName=$_.LogName; ProviderName=$logProviders; StartTime=$startDate; EndTime=$endDate; Level=2}
    Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $filter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

Comment: @nimizen: "04.01.2022" is a string, but legime date entry and it works great in first example (...logname="*";providername="*cluster*"...) giving some records back, so it's definitely not the problem.

Comment: I agree, it's not the problem, but this is Theo's answer, I just edited it as the code wan't formatted correctly. The Microsoft documentation does indicate that the ProviderName should take wildcards, but in my testing it still requires at least one alphanumeric character to function correctly and return results. Running your code without 'ContinueSilently' does illicit some error output which you might be able to use to investigate further.

Comment: yes, this is probably the poit: there must be at least one alphanumeric character, so still the question: how to show all errors in a given timespan?

Comment: @Purclot Please see my edit

Comment: thanks, it works with the loop, but the performance is..how to say it...not the fastest one.. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

How I would do it with a foreach-object loop.  All lognames should cover all providers.  In powershell 7, you can do foreach-object -parallel, and it took me under 2 seconds.  Trying an enum for level;  I'm surprised it still needs casting to int.  This may really be a question about invoke-command.

```
$list = 1..10 | % tostring comp000
invoke-command $list {  # runs in parallel
  get-winevent -listlog * -ea 0 | 
  % { Get-WinEvent @{logname=$_.logname; 
  starttime='4/1'; endtime='5/31'; 
  level=[int][Diagnostics.Tracing.EventLevel]::Error} -ea 0 } 
}
```

Comment: nice! Unfortunately I don't have PS 7 on that server, firewall is blocked so I only can use the script with "invoke-command....", etc. so it "takes" time..

Comment: Hmm only takes me 9 seconds without the -parallel.  Note that `invoke-command comp1,comp2,comp3` runs in parallel in itself.